# Error in cyttsp4 (linux kernel) Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

The below is the Makefile for cyttsp4 inside the Linux kernel that I'm compiling for Android, using the kyasu msm8974 project (https://github.com/kyasu/android_kernel_samsung_msm8974).

```
### CYTTSP
#obj-m  += cyttsp4.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_core.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_i2c.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_platform.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_devtree.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_mt_common.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_mtb.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_btn.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_debug.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_device_access.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_loader.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o

CY_CFLAG_ADD =\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICETREE_SUPPORT\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_BUTTON\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICE_ACCESS\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_LOADER\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PLATFORM_FW_UPGRADE\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_BINARY_FW_UPGRADE

CY_CFLAG_REMOVE =\
    -DCYTTSP4_PDATA_IN_PLATFORM_C\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PROXIMITY\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PLATFORM_TTCONFIG_UPGRADE\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICE_ACCESS_API\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEBUG\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_MANUAL_TTCONFIG_UPGRADE

CFLAGS_cyttsp4_core.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_i2c.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_spi.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mta.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mtb.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_a.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_b.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_common.o      += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_btn.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_proximity.o      += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o  += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_device_access.o  += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_test_device_access_api.o += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_loader.o         += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_debug.o          += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_devtree.o        += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_platform.o       += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG

CFLAGS_cyttsp4_core.o           -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_i2c.o            -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_spi.o            -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mta.o            -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mtb.o            -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_a.o           -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_b.o           -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_common.o      -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_btn.o            -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_proximity.o      -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o  -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_device_access.o  -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_test_device_access_api.o -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_loader.o         -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_debug.o          -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_devtree.o        -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_platform.o       -= $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
/home/USER/Projects/OS/android_kernel_samsung_msm8974/drivers/gpu/gpu_sysfs/Kbuild:29: **** Make sure target file is defined. Check the TARGET and GPU configs in Makefile and Kernel Config. Module won't work without target file. ****
/home/USER/Projects/OS/android_kernel_samsung_msm8974/drivers/input/touchscreen/cyttsp4/Makefile:50: *** missing separator.  Stop.
scripts/Makefile.clean:94: recipe for target 'drivers/input/touchscreen/cyttsp4' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen/cyttsp4] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.clean:94: recipe for target 'drivers/input/touchscreen' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.clean:94: recipe for target 'drivers/input' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/input] Error 2
Makefile:1201: recipe for target '_clean_drivers' failed
make: *** [_clean_drivers] Error 2
```

Comment: First time hear about `-=` operator in Make. And cannot find any evidence that it is supported.

Comment: I'm not very used to Makefiles, I usually use CMake to generate them and don't edit them manually so seeing += made me think -= also existed, but you're right, I can't find it either. I fixed it by replacing all the -= entries with $(filter-out, $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp_thing.o)), seems to work properly now, strange that the people that made Cyttsp4 driver could even make an error like that...

Comment: As your solution works, you could think about providing an answer. If someone else find better solution (like patched version of `make`), it will be just another answer.

Comment: Good idea, was too excited once I got it working, thanks to you I got the kernel to compile and I've now successfully ported a like 90% functioning Nethunter OS for Android on Samsung S4 i9506 :) I'll answer this in a couple minutes, using my S4 as a keyboard and mouse :D

Answer (score 0):

This is (partially) written using my S4 i9506 as a keyboard, if you want Nethunter on your S4 comment your interest and ill get started on a guide to port it yourself. I'll make one soon anyway but if people are interested I'll put more effort into making a guide to porting Nethunter faster.

Basically, as mentioned by @Tsyvarev, there's no -= command in Makefiles. Basically, whoever made the Makefile for Cyttsp4 (at least in the kernel sources I had) didn't do a very good job and after some research they probably thought just like me that the separator missing error was due to a missing tab somewhere which everyone suggests when you search for this issue. A quick search with @Tsyvarev's info about -= not existing I found the proper way to do what they want. Here's the complete Makefile with the proper alteration. You use $(filter-out, VARS_TO_REMOVE, RESULT) to remove flags.

The error is so stupid I don't see how it was made in the first place, considering it was found inside the source code of a kernel, and  the people that make kernels are generally not this unskilled, or else they wouldn't be making kernels.

Wait a minute... I'm making errors and I'm... Oh...

Anyway, here's the code!

```
### CYTTSP
#obj-m  += cyttsp4.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_core.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_i2c.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_platform.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_devtree.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_mt_common.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_mtb.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_btn.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_debug.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_device_access.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_loader.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4) += cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o

CY_CFLAG_ADD =\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICETREE_SUPPORT\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_BUTTON\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICE_ACCESS\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_LOADER\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PLATFORM_FW_UPGRADE\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_BINARY_FW_UPGRADE

CY_CFLAG_REMOVE =\
    -DCYTTSP4_PDATA_IN_PLATFORM_C\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PROXIMITY\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_PLATFORM_TTCONFIG_UPGRADE\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEVICE_ACCESS_API\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_DEBUG\
    -DCONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_CYPRESS_CYTTSP4_MANUAL_TTCONFIG_UPGRADE

CFLAGS_cyttsp4_core.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_i2c.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_spi.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mta.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mtb.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_a.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_b.o           += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_common.o      += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_btn.o            += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_proximity.o      += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o  += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_device_access.o  += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_test_device_access_api.o += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_loader.o         += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_debug.o          += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD)
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_devtree.o        += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_platform.o       += $(CY_CFLAG_ADD) -DDEBUG

CFLAGS_cyttsp4_core.o           := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_core.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_i2c.o            := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_i2c.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_spi.o            := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_spi.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mta.o            := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mta.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mtb.o            := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mtb.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_a.o           := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_a.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_b.o           := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_b.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_common.o      := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_mt_common.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_btn.o            := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_btn.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_proximity.o      := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_proximity.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o      := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_samsung_sysfs.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_device_access.o      := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_device_access.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_test_device_access_api.o     := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_test_device_access_api.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_loader.o         := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_loader.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_debug.o          := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_debug.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_devtree.o        := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_devtree.o))
CFLAGS_cyttsp4_platform.o       := $(filter-out $(CY_CFLAG_REMOVE),$(CFLAGS_cyttsp4_platform.o))
```